# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shapeless.DefaultSymbolicLabelling$.instance(Lshapeless/HList;)Lshapeless/DefaultSymbolicLabelling;

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, log4j, spark-submit

I am trying to run the spark job using the spark-submit command and getting this error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:shapeless.DefaultSymbolicLabelling$.instance(Lshapeless/HList;)Lshapeless/DefaultSymbolicLabelling;
at io.home.windowGateway.ConfigLoader$anon$exportedReader$macro$268$1.inst$macro$1$lzycompute(ConfigLoader.scala:24)
    at io.home.windowGateway.ConfigLoader$anon$exportedReader$macro$268$1.inst$macro$1(ConfigLoader.scala:24)
    at io.home.windowGateway.ConfigLoader$.<init>(ConfigLoader.scala:24)
    at io.home.windowGateway.ConfigLoader$.<clinit>(ConfigLoader.scala)
    at io.home.windowGateway$.main(test.scala:23)
    at io.home.windowGateway.test.main(test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info
```

The control is not even going into the spark. My spark session looks like this-

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("test")
      .master("spark://dheerajHome:7077")
      .getOrCreate()
```

The URL in the master is the spark master URL. And the server is up and running.
And my spark-submit command is

```
spark-submit --name test --class io.home.windowGateway ~/Desktop/jar/spark-data-export-0.1.0.jar
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when running spark job in google dataproc

Adding this to the sbt file worked for me:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.common.@1").inAll
)
```

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-java-dependencies-apache-spark-applications-cloud-dataproc